# Hosting multiple unnamed sites on same EC2 box

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that I can have multiple websites hosted on the same EC2 box. The way I'm doing it is pointing Route 53 for the domain to the same box and in my httpd.conf file I'm adding something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website1"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works great for websites that have an assigned domain name.

What if I am still working on a site/application and don't have a domain name assigned to it?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <==what goes here if I don't have a domain name yet?
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this even possible?

I tried just taking the IP of the box and going here: 54.32.XX.XX/website2/index.html

But this gives a 404.

How do I properly access this subdirectory?

Of note, the side in `website1` is what I get when I just go directly to the IP (54.32.XX.XX) which I wouldn't expect since I have another site in the "main" directory `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Maybe you can create a temporary subdomain like dev.mywebsite.com and point it to website2 until you get the actual domain

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy That's a good idea and should work.